# necesito una sentencia sql para traer los 2 registros mas recientes de una base de datos empleados (emp)

Tags: sql, oracle

EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO

---

```
  7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17/12/80        800                    20
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20/02/81       1600        300         30
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22/02/81       1250        500         30
  7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02/04/81       2975                    20
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28/09/81       1250       1400         30
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01/05/81       2850                    30
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09/06/81       2450                    10
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09/12/82       3000                    20
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17/11/81       5000                    10
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08/09/81       1500          0         30
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12/01/83       1100                    20

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
```

---

```
  7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03/12/81        950                    30
  7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03/12/81       3000                    20
  7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23/01/82       1300                    10
```

tengo esta base de datos y necesito sacar los dos datos mas recientes de esta tabla.
ya se como sacar el mas recientes con max (hiredate) pero no se como sacar el dato anterior al maximo.

no puedo usar (rownum)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! intentaste algo?

Answer (score 2):

toca hacer un truco con el rownum:

```
select *
from (
    select
        *, ROWNUM as rownum
    from latabla
    order by hiredate desc
) as tabla
where rownum <= 2
```

Eso debería funcionar.

Y por lo que veo en internet con oracle 12g en adelante se puede hacer esto:

```
select *
from latabla
order by hiredate desc
fetch first 2 rows only
```

Comment: eso solo trae el primero.. esto no contesta la ptregunta, solo trae la primera (en oracle no hay limit, eso es exclusivo de mysql)

Comment: cierto.... vayamos con el rownum trick. Ya la edito

Comment: mejorrrr.. aunque no entiendo para que hacer un subselect cuando podes poner el where directamente al select en el primer caso..., es mas, la columna rownum no necesitas traerla en el select

Comment: No digo que no.... pero no tengo el manejador frente a mi para probar asi que.... :-)

Comment: creeme, que es asi ;) https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Comment: no lo dudo, @gbianchi